# Define object structure for an object used in state with TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to define the structure of an object, I am using in react state. The object looks like this

```
{
    1: [{foo: 'whatever', bar: 'another string'}],
    2: [{foo: 'yet another string', bar: '...'}],
    ...
}
```

Currently I am trying it like this

```
interface ObjectStructure {
    number: [{
        foo: string,
        bar: string
    }]
}
const [data, setData] = useState<ObjectStructure>({} as ObjectStructure );
```

But that is not working. When I try

```
data[dynamicKey]...
```

I get

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{} | { number: [{ foo: string; bar: string; }]; }'

I assume the problem is that

```
number: [{...}]
^
|
|
```

How to define this object structure in TypeScript with React?

Comment: Does `useState<Record<number, [{ foo: string; bar: string }]>>` satisfy your needs?

Comment: @spender When I try something like `setData({1: [foo: 'a', bar: 'b']}`, it gives me `Type '[{ foo: string; barstring; }, { foo: string; bar: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[{ foo: string; bar: string; }]'.   Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.` And it highlights the number (key) `1`

Comment: So, there might be more than a single object in the array? Then `useState<Record<number, { foo: string; bar: string }[]>>` might be better for you

Comment: @spender ah, that did it. I did not know about `record`. Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, in your original type you are declaring an interface which accepts a single member called `"number"`. To allow the keys to be any `number` you'd specify the key as `[key: number]: [{ ... your stuff here ... }]`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an index signature:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
interface ObjectStructure {
    [index: number]: [{
        foo: string,
        bar: string
    }]
}
const [data, setData] = useState<ObjectStructure>({} as ObjectStructure );
data[0] = [{
    foo: "",
    bar: ""
}]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUMAHb5QkMEDyARgCt0jbFGSNktRMzhy4AbXYATdAA8AXHDbIQ-dFAC6WhQlnyLJCBC2oYUdgHMANOYtz+OKLftO3RQ2ZCZnoINjtFZTwcZzgMGAARaMM4AF4UDGw8dAAeAWFRewkYKXQAPgAKBGIcVDh8kRgxYtK4AEoAbmYo3AUABhT0038rGzgAInHXC09vCfGgwyA)

You could also use the `Record` predefined type type to create the index signature:

```
interface ObjectStructure extends Record<number, [{
        foo: string,
        bar: string
    }]>{}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUMAHb5QkMEDyARgCt0jbFGSNktOOgAe+NgBNUcAEojoigDxtkIfuigAaOAG0EzOFetWSECAC44qGFHYBzI5ZvX+OKE4ubmzu3laEALoAfAiEYXDM9BBsLmaKeDgmGDAAIhkRcAC8KBjYeOhaAsKirhIwUuhRABSxcDgqVSIwYnUNcACUANzM6bimAAwFxebxdo5wAEQLXjZ+AYsLzJFAA)

Or using a type alias:

```
type ObjectStructure = Record<number, [{ foo: string, bar: string}]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUDAJ5gEDyARgFbpG2KMkbJacALxwASoOgATADwA7ZCB7ooAGjgBtJCQgQAXHFQwowFQHNdPHFDMWrtwgF0AfMzi+4zeggVC30FPBxdDBgAEXD3KRQMbDx0JV4BIUtRGHF0TwAKBGIcVDh0wRhhbNy4AEoAbmYw3D0ABnjpAx8-I1M4ACJ+7W7fBycB-uYPIA)

If you want the properties to be arrays you should use `Array<foo: string,bar: string }>`, the syntax you are using means a an array with a single element of that type. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUMAHb5QkMEDyARgCt0jbFGSNktOOgAe+NgBNUcAEojoigDxtkIfuigAaOAEEoUHAE8tCZnAekIEAFxxUMKOwDmR+4-4cKDcPLzZvZkIAPijEImZmegg2DzgAbUU8HBMMGAARLIBdOABeFAxsPHQtAWFRTwkYKXQogAoEYhwVWpEYMUbmgEoAbmZM3DSABmKytLtHJ1c4ACJlvwXA4JXlyJN5xxJnN1X1gKDjncJCoA)